# Dealing with perfectly confounded microarray experiment

Tags: experiment-design, confounding, microarray

I need to compare microarray data, where all of the "cases" were hybridized in one batch and all of the "controls" in another, so I have no way of removing this batch effect.

What would be the best strategy to detect differentially expressed genes (if at all possible)?

Comment: I'm not very experienced with microarray data, but I'd say tread carefully. You might be able to do some normalization using household genes, if at all, but even this is not a substitute for what should have be done in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Thats really the only possibility I've been considering myself.